# TFS code review how to review code against older version that is not prior version or version in a different branch

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

We would like to use the TFS 2012 Code Review but ran into a snag
where we need to compare the current version to the version from 3 changes ago (or compare it to the version in a different branch (e.g. Main or Release branch).

Does this type of compare along with adding comments/overall comments during the Code Review exist in TFS?

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today it is only possible to do a Code Review on a specific changeset (or shelveset).  That means only one revision.  If you wanted to do what you are suggesting, the only way to do it today would be to initiate 3 code reviews, one for each of the 3 changesets.

Something we (the TFS MVP's) have been asking Microsoft for a while, is the ability to do a code-review on many changesets at once (which is effectively what you're asking for).

There is a User-Voice suggestion which covers the multi-changeset review and other Code Review related features, go and vote on it: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2670048-make-code-review-feature-usable

Comment: Also, we need the ability to do the code review so we can compare the current modified code in Dev branch against the code in the Main branch (or other branch).  This is critical.. So, the code review code compare needs to be configurable on what files are compared and not so limiting.  The code review compare should be almost as flexible as the regular TFS compare.

Comment: For going between branches I usually don't use Code Review at all.  If I need somebody to review code before it goes into MAIN, I just have the reviewer do the merge.  Then he can easily review the differences as part of doing the merge, and choose to commit the merge or not based on his review.